# Trying to find if array is full or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm working with JQuery to determine if an array, built earlier, with a determined number of indexes, is full or not.
When created, array looks like this :

```
,,,,,,
```

All I want to do is find if every position is filled or not.

So bascially, i'm trying to test if and only if

```
[x,x,x,x,x,x]
```

For example, if

```
[x,x,x,,x,x]  or if [x,,,,,] //return false, wrong...
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fill your initial array with nulls, like:

```js
const arr = Array(9).fill(null);
```

Then you can use [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or [every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) like this:

```js
// check if a null doesn't exist
!arr.some(element => element === null)

// check if every element is not null
arr.every(element => element !== null)
```

Use whichever you like, since both of them breaks the loop when a null is found.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need any specific jQuery stuff to read the size of an array. Just vanilla javascript has what you need.

```
var arrayMaxValues = 4;
var testArray = [1,2,3,4];

if ( testArray.length == arrayMaxValues )
{
  alert( 'Array is full!' );
}
else if ( testArray.length > arrayMaxValues )
{
  alert( 'Array is overstuffed!' );
} else {
  alert( 'There's plenty of room!' );
}
```

### EDIT

Ah, you re-typed your question.  So, you want to see if they array has zero null or undefined values?

```
function isArrayFull( arr )
{
  for ( var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++ )
  {
    if ( 'undefined' == typeof arr[i] || null === arr[i] )
    {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I think what he's after is more like trying to figure out if any of the values in the array are null or the empty string.

Comment: I think you're wrong mate, as the array's length will always be equal to arrayMaxValues. I'm not trying to find out it's length and compare it, but if for each index entry, there is an associated value != to ''.

Comment: If you intend on using jQuery syntax, you can use $.each(arr, function(index, value) { // logic here }); too.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is doing the same as Peter Bailey's function, but I only wanted to share it since it's a different approach using the built-in power of array filtering.

So, since the full array has a predetermined length you could filter it against 'undefined' and null and compare lengths, like this:

```
function isArrayFull(arr) {
   return arr.length === arr.filter(function(o) {
     return typeof o !== 'undefined' ||  o !== null;
   }).length;
}
```